# Default Values from strings.xml appear in Android Studio but not when I run the app

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following the [Building your First App](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) tutorial. I'm using Android Studio 2.3.1

I have default values in strings.xml. When I reference these in the design editor, they show up correctly in the design preview and the XML. However, when I run the app on a device, no text appears. There are no errors or warnings. I've tried multiple devices.

[strings appearing correctly in the design editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZMtE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are setting the string content in the tools text field (the one with the wrench on left). You have to set the string content in the empty field above.

If you set the string content with `tools:text`, it will apply only to preview layout.

If you set the string content with `android:text` it will apply both to preview and to rendered layout.

If you set both, the `tools:text` field will have more priority than `android:text` field on preview and the `android:text` field will be used for rendering.

Comment: Thanks! Big help :)

Answer (score 1):

Check those properties again.

You have the string in the text property with a **wrench**. If you look at the XML, you will see `tools:text`. That's a text property that you can only see in the preview (to test with dimensions and things like that, like you had real text on the component).

The real text one is `android:text`.

[image]

Comment: thanks! I gave the answer to @Fondesa because he came in first

Comment: oops, I checked the time stamps and was certain I picked the earliest. I guess I did the opposite :)